Proving a metric space is not complete using an analysis of parity

I am wondering if I have made any mistakes in my proof of d). I am thinking it is too simple compared to the other sections of the question, and I didn't make use of the hint. Have I made mistakes? How would you do it using the hint?
Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $(a_n)$ converges to a rational, say $k := \frac{a}{b}$. Take $\epsilon > 0$, then there is some $M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{M} \leq \epsilon$, so for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ we must have $d(a_n, k) \leq \frac{1}{M}$ for all $n \geq N$.
This implies that $\frac{1}{2^{f(ba_n - a) - f(b)}} \leq \frac{1}{M}$. So it must be that $f(ba_n - a) - f(b) \geq M$. Since $ba_n$ is even, it must be that $a_n$ is also even, otherwise we have an even - odd which is odd, and $f(ba_n - a) = 0$.
So lets write $ba_n = 2^xw$, $a = 2^yz$, where $w, z$ are odd integers. Since $w, z$ are odd, then $w - z$ is even, so write $w - z = 2^pl$. Choose $a' = 2^y(z - 2^{p+1}k)$ for some odd number $k$. Then we have $f(ba_n - a') = f(ba_n - a)$.
Proof: If $x > y$, then $f(ba_n - a') = f(2^xw - 2^y(z - 2^{p + 1}k)) = f(2^y(2^{x-y}w - (z - 2^{p + 1}k)) = f(2^yj)$ where $j$ is odd. Hence $f(ba_n - a') = y = f(2^y(2^{x - y}w - z)) = f(ba_n - a)$.
If $x < y$, then $f(ba_n - a') = f(2^xw - 2^y(z - 2^{p + 1}k)) = f(2^x(w - 2^{y -x}(z - 2^{p + 1}k)) = f(2^xj)$ where $j$ is odd. Hence $f(ba_n - a') = x = f(2^x(w - 2^{y - x}z)) = f(ba_n - a)$.
If $x = y$ then $f(ba_n - a') = f(2^xw - 2^y(z - 2^{p + 1}k)) = f(2^y(w - (z - 2^{p + 1}k))) = f(2^y(w - z + 2^{p + 1}k))) = f(2^y(2^pl + 2^{p + 1}k))) = f(2^y(2^p(l - 2k))) = y + p = f(ba_n - a) = f(2^x(w - z)) = f(2^x(2^pl)) = x + p$.
Hence, we can deduce that $(a_n)$ converges to two distinct values, a contradiction.
